# how to use Rg.Plugins.Popup with Prism for Xamarin forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, navigation, prism

I am having a trouble showing the popup pages using Prism navigation Method.

The plugin is called: Rg.Plugins.Popup

Normally, you can use it without prism as:

```
var loadingPage = new LoadingPopupPage(); 
await Navigation.PushPopupAsync(loadingPage);
await Task.Delay(2000);
await Navigation.RemovePopupPageAsync(loadingPage);
```

I tried that , but apparently , I can't access the INavigaion Navigation object to push pages as modals

so, I tried to use prism's navigation:

```
await _navigationService.NavigateAsync("?", useModalNavigation: true);
```

Here, the method takes the name of the page, but I can't register the "loadingPage" since it's a popup page with no viewmodel

I also tried to nest the page in a navigation page and navigate to it after registering it. but nothing appears to me.

Any help will be appreciated .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already answered on GitHub. No 3rd party libraries can or will be supported directly from Prism. However support for adding PopupPage's from Rg.Plugins.Popup is supported with Prism.Plugin.Popups.

The plugin is of course [open source](https://github.com/dansiegel/Prism.Plugin.Popups). There is a full sample in the repo. When using Prism 7 be sure to use the `Prism.Plugin.Popups` package and not one of the container specific packages as this is no longer necessary. Also as of today it is still in preview until Rg.Plugins.Popup releases a new "stable" package.

Comment: I did registered the PopupNavigation instance in the App.xaml.cs but when I do this: NavigationService.PushPopupPageAsync("MyPopupPage") in my viewModel,  I have an error saying that INavigationService does not contain the definition for PushPopupPageAsync. What could be the problem?

Comment: Again. That was deprecated and removed from the API. You just need to call NavigateAsync